# VBA copy sheet from a .XLSX and insert it into a .XLA file

Tags: excel, vba, xlsx, worksheet, xla

I'm trying to copy a Sheet from a `.XLSX` file as a hidden sheet in a `.XLA` file.

I only managed to copy from `.XLA -> XLSX`, but not `XLSX -> XLA`.

Take a look at my two functions:

```
Sub copyFromXLAtoXLSX()
    temp.Sheet1.Copy Workbooks(1).Sheets(1)  
End Sub

Sub copyFromXLSXtoXLA()
    ' It gives me the error: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error  
    Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Copy temp.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  
End Sub
```

[image: (left) copyFromXLAtoXLSXand (right) copyFromXLSXtoXLA]

Any help is really welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XLA sheets collection cannot be accessed for adding a new sheet as long as `.IsAddIn=True`. Try to set the XLA workbook to `.isAddIn = False`, make your copy and then set it back to `True`.

I think it should be (to be tested):

```
Sub copyFromXLSXtoXLA()
    Workbooks(1).IsAddIn = False '<-- set it false
    Workbooks(1).Sheets(1).Copy temp.ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)  
    Workbooks(1).IsAddIn = True '<-- set it back to true
End Sub
```